# When using new inside a function call what do you free? as below in the boost call

Tags: c++, std

Does there need to be an associated free with the new inside the function call for sdt::locale

```
static boost::posix_time::ptime getPosixTimeFromDateString( string dString )
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    ptime timeDate;
    const std::locale loc = std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%d"));
    std::istringstream is(dateString);
    is.imbue(loc);

    boost::posix_time::ptime t;
    is >> timeDate;
    return( timeDate );
}
```

If not why not, if so what do you free, should the boost object have been created outside of the function call?

Answer (score 2):

No, because the locale's destructor is responsible for it. This is stated explicitly in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale#Notes):

> Overload (7) is typically called with its second argument obtained directly from a *`new`-expression*: the locale is responsible for calling the matching `delete` from its own destructor.

Overload (7) is:

> ```
> template<class Facet>
> locale(const locale& other, Facet* f);
> ```

Comment: Thanks much, I was asked this question earlier by another developer. He wasnt sure and neither was I so I took it up to research it. I did google the std::locale for documentation but c++ but now that I see it I went to the destructers page, misread it and thought it was slim. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/~locale